# Undefined references when compiling gSOAP client

Tags: c, gsoap

I'm trying to create a client for a web service in C. I was generated C files with the wsdl2h and soapcpp2. In netbeans I'm added the generated files and the gSOAP include dir to the project's include directories.
my main file looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <soapH.h>
#include <webserviceSoap12.nsmap>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    struct soap *soap1 = soap_new();
    struct _ns1__getAllCustomer *quote;
    struct _ns1__getAllCustomerResponse *quote2;
    if (soap_call___ns2__getAllCustomer(soap1, NULL, NULL, quote, quote2) == SOAP_OK)
        printf("asd\n");
    else // an error occurred  
        soap_print_fault(soap1, stderr); // display the SOAP fault on the stderr stream
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I copied the most of this from the gSOAP website's getting started section.
When I try to compile i get the following error:

```
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
\NetBeansProjects\WebServiceClient/main.c:19: undefined reference to `soap_new_LIBRARY_VERSION_REQUIRED_20808'
\NetBeansProjects\WebServiceClient/main.c:22: undefined reference to `soap_call___ns2__getAllCustomer'
\NetBeansProjects\WebServiceClient/main.c:25: undefined reference to `soap_print_fault'
```

If I add the "soapC.c" "soapClient.c" "soapClientLib.c" files to the project I get a bunch of more undefinied reference. 
What am I doing wrong? I'm using Netbeans ide with MinGW compiler on Win7. What other libraries I need or what other files should I include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by adding the files "soapC.c" "soapClient.c" "stdsoap.c" to the project files and in the Project propertie - Include Directories adding the files generated by soapcpp2 and the gSOAP toolkit's gsoap directory

Answer (score 1):

You will need to link in the proper libraries. You will need to add the appropriate libraries using the `-l` switch and you will optionally need to pass the path to where these libraries reside via `-L`. Also, note that the libraries ending with a `++` are typically the ones you should use if you're using C++. So, your command line shoulde include at least:

For C:

```
gcc ... -lgsoap -L/path/to/gsoap/binaries
```

For C++:

```
g++ ... -lgsoap++ -L/path/to/gsoap/binaries
```

Also, depending on whether you're using additional features such as SSL, cookies etc. you will need to link these libraries in too:

```
g++ ... -lgsoap++ -lgsoapssl++ -L/path/...
```

If you're using a different toolchain, lookup the documentation for the exact switches.

Comment: You might wish to tailor your advice to the fact that the question is about doing this from C (and gsoap appears to support both).

Comment: and where should I find this library? I downloaded the gSOAP toolkit but it's not contains any library.

Comment: @DonalFellows: I did mention "Also, note that the libraries ending with a ++ are typically the ones you should use if you're using C++" though of course the examples could be better.

Comment: Apparently linking with different variants fo the library does not work since (unluckily) those static libraries contain duplicate symbols: e.g. using -lsoapssl++ and -lgsoapck++ leads to (at least) a duplicated _soap_code_str symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in *Debian BullsEye (11)*, `-lgsoap++` is necessary and it was solved when I added `/gsoap_library_path/libgsoap++.a` to g++ compiler command line.